# I can't export apk on ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

it turns out that when using the `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` command, it doesn't compile showing the following error.

[first part of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PfvC.png)

[second part of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNezU.png)

this is my ionic info.

[ionic info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfKhK.png)

I don't know what to do, the posts I've seen don't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

remove angularfire2 package and reinstall it

```
npm uninstall angularfire2
```

then re install:

```
npm i angularfire2 --save
```